# Sound volume decreasing for no apparent reason

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder

I have an iOS app using SwiftUI. It handles a few sound files and performs some audio recording. This is the function doing the recording work:

```
func recordAudio(to file: String, for duration: TimeInterval) {
    let audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    
    do {try audioSession.setCategory(.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
        
        let audioFilename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(file+".m4a"),
            audioURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: audioFilename),
            settings = [
                AVFormatIDKey: Int(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
                AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
                AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.high.rawValue
                ]

        audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(url: audioURL, settings: settings)
        audioRecorder.delegate = self
        audioRecorder.record(forDuration: TimeInterval(2.0))
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed -- Recording !!! -> \(error)")
    }
}
```

At this point, it basically works, but there is a strange behaviour that I neither understand nor like.

Here is the problem:

When I start the app and play a sound file, the volume is right for my taste.
Then without ever adjusting the volume I perform some recording (using the function above).
Finally after the recording is done, I go back to the file I played just before and play it again; the volume has mysteriously gone down, without me knowing why.

Is there something in my function that could explain that?
Or some other cause that someone could think of?

If I restart the app, the volume automatically goes back to normal.
For information, I am using iOS 14.4.2 and Xcode 12.4.

Comment: If you change your audio session to .playback when only playing (and not recording), does that fix it?

Comment: I was not actually using any audio session when only playing.
But changing the code, setting the audio session back to .playback after recording solved the problem indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The audio session will be a decreased volume during playback after recording in `.playAndRecord` mode. After recording, explicitly set to something like `.playback` to get the volume you're expecting.